# Transform doesnt animate when added class with transform: scale(1) via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to insert a new div with fancy transform: scale() animation when button is clicked, however it doesn't animate. I am not sure why. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```js
$("button").click(event => {
    
    let div = $("<div></div>");
    div.insertAfter("button");
    div.addClass("animate");
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #000;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.animate{
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break up the *adding the `div`* and *adding a class to it*, e.g. using a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

W/o the above, the animation won't apply the *transition*, as it does all in one go.

Stack snippet

```js
$("button").click(event => {
    
    let div = $("<div></div>");
    div.insertAfter("button");
    setTimeout(function() {
      div.addClass("animate");
    }, 10)
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #000;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.animate{
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
```

---

If you use `animation` on the other hand, it will work

Stack snippet

```js
$("button").click(event => {
    
    let div = $("<div></div>");
    div.insertAfter("button");
    div.addClass("animate");
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #000;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.animate{
  animation: scale 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes scale {
  from { transform: scale(0); }
  to   { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: @DoeJane Yes (and no), the minimum is 4ms I think, and for older browsers it might be more. For most newer browsers it will still work even with 1ms, just test it properly.

Comment: @DoeJane You're welcome...and now you got enough reps. to be able to upvote :)

Answer (score -2):

how it seems to me that it's better to use `@keyframes` and you don't need to use `addClass`

```js
$("button").click(event => {
    
    let div = $("<div></div>");
    div.insertAfter("button");
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #000;
  animation: scale 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes scale {
  from { transform: scale(0); }
  to   { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: I posted on my point of view a better solution. There is no point in using the method `addClass` @LGSon

Comment: Using a separate class for the animation is definitely better than have it hard coded, as with that it can be altered, added or removed.

Comment: This is not a hard code, DoeJoe wrote a task with a certain case. Using the additional jquery method is not the best way for performance. I'm not against your decision - it's absolutely correct and there is a place to be, but it seems to me that for the current case it is better for him to use the solution is simpler, namely mine.